# No Agent Queue Found

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I recently exported and imported a VSTS build process definition to create a similar build for a similar project. However, when I try to save the definition, VSTS displays an error that:

"No agent queue was found with identifier *x*."

Does anyone know of a cause? I looked at some other online posts and they were related to security settings, which are all correct.

There are also a few related to building capabilities, but this is not that exception.

Answer (score 9):

When you import a build definition, it pulls across all the values from drop-downs, including the "Default agent queue". For projects in the same VSTS account, this value ("Hosted" in my case) will have the same name in the original definition and the new definition you are creating. However, the IDs may be different or not "hooked up" correctly by the import process.

1. Select the "Process" header before the beginning of your task list.
2. Click the "Default agent queue" drop-down.
3. Select your "other" agent pool that has the same name. In my case, there were 2 items named "Hosted". I picked the one that was not already selected.

Now your build will save and queue.